# Why recoil state is not updated? (solved with useRecoilCallback and snapshot, but wonder why it happened)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, recoiljs

*BEFORE BEGIN: Please note that I resolved the problem with useRecoilCallback and snapshot, but just wonder why it happened*

Here's my code for managing popups in my project

This project is made with React 18.2, Next 13.4, Recoil 0.7.7

## Original code

atomPopupList.ts

```js
export const atomPopupList = atom<Array<IPopup>>({
    default: [],
    key: 'atomPopupList',
});
```

usePopup.ts

```js
const usePopup = () => {
    const { randomIdGenerator } = useRandom();

    const [
        popups,
        setPopupList,
    ] = useRecoilState(atomPopupList);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('test if it is updated', popups);
    }, [popups]);

    const openPopup = (popup: Omit<IPopup, 'id'>, customId?: string) => {
        const regPopup: IPopup = {
            ...popup,
            id: customId || randomIdGenerator(),
        };
        console.log('check popup list exists', popups);
        setPopupList([
            ...popups,
            regPopup,
        ]);
    };

    const closePopup = (id: string) => {
        setPopupList(popups.filter((p) => p.id !== id));
    };

    return { openPopup, closePopup };
};

export default usePopup;
```

- note that console.log are for explanation

### About Code

- function 'openPopup' is used for registering popup into popup list which is managed by recoil. (atomPopupList)
- I manage popups with its own, random generated IDs

### Problem

- I have several nested popups, and tried to open them.
- First popup worked well. It is successfully registered into recoil state, useEffect also executed as popup list is updated.
- and I opened second popup while first popup is opened, then I noticed that popup list atom is empty from the beginning

  - console.log inside openPopup function showed empty array

### Solve

- I searched web and found 'useRecoilCallback' and 'snapshot' can be used for keeping your atom as recent as new.
- So, I changed code into below one

fixed usePopup.ts

```js
const usePopup = () => {
    const { randomIdGenerator } = useRandom();

    const openPopup = useRecoilCallback(
        ({ set, snapshot }) =>
            async (popup: Omit<IPopup, 'id'>, customId?: string) => {
                const popupList = await snapshot.getPromise(atomPopupList);
                const regPopup: IPopup = {
                    ...popup,
                    id: customId || randomIdGenerator(),
                };
                set(atomPopupList, [
                    ...popupList,
                    regPopup,
                ]);
            },
        [],
    );

    const closePopup = useRecoilCallback(
        ({ set, snapshot }) =>
            async (id: string) => {
                const popupList = await snapshot.getPromise(atomPopupList);
                set(
                    atomPopupList,
                    popupList.filter((p) => p.id !== id),
                );
            },
        [],
    );

    return { openPopup, closePopup };
};

export default usePopup;
```

...and now it works well (until now)

### Question

- Why recoil state is not updated?

  - As I mentioned earlier, with first openPopup function, popup list is updated and useEffect also worked.
  - But when I tried to open second popup, it was gone.